# Error Code 215: twitter search api?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-search

I am using the twitter search API 1.1 and getting this response

```
 {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

The query I am constructing for search is

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=.priyanka%20chopra
```

Am I making the right query or not? Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The query seems OK, but, are you authenticating your request via OAuth?

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview